# How to sign XML in Scala with RFC 3275 standart?

Tags: xml, scala, x509certificate, xml-dsig

I am looking for an implementation of automatically signing XML request with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature). However I do not think it is a good idea to put values directly in the code. And I have several unclear point:

- How should I import (read: how it is normally done) digest value, signature value, X509 certificate to the code?
- Is there a way to implement it without third party libraries?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? As it stands, this question seems very broad...

Comment: Also please refrain from asking multiple questions in one.